# Mule select where like query with wild cards failing

Tags: mule, spring-jdbc

How do you execute a query with like parameters with wild cards in Mule.

I wish to execute a query with

```
select OrganizationID from organizations where webaddress like '%#[flowVars['FromAddressDomain']]'

<jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="LookUpOrg" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="IssueTrakDataConnector" doc:name="DatabaseLookupOrg">
        <jdbc:query key="LookUpOrg" value="select OrganizationID from organizations where webaddress like ('%#[payload]')"/>

    </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
```

but this fails with error due to the presence of quotes, removing them gives a different error.

former=false}. Message payload is of type: String  Exception Cause::com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.

kindly help.

regards
Santosh

Comment: Made headway, i concatenated the payload with the wildcard string and passed it as a argument and that worked.
    <set-payload value="%#[flowVars['FromAddressDomain']]" doc:name="Set Payload"> <jdbc:query key="LookUpOrg" value="select OrganizationID from organizations where webaddress like (#[payload])">

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve this.  
the error i face when using this query statement is 

<jdbc:query key="lookupmail" value="select top 5 * from maildata where FROMEMAILADDRESS like %#[flowVars['str']]%"></jdbc:query> 

Root Exception stack trace:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CONCAT() function.

```
select OrganizationID from organizations where webaddress like CONCAT('%', #[payload:?])
```